Google Sheet Range option not working when I embed it on a web page
The range= option is not working for me. Can someone please let me know what the correct syntax needs to be.
I just need to hide columns A & B and when I add range="C1:F100", it still shows the 1st two columns.
Here is my code:
<iframe range="C1:F200" height="800" width="1350" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/####9nVZ/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;&amp;headers=false"></iframe>

I have tried it with quotes and without also changed the location of the range option in the iframe with no success.
